# how to solve this internal server error

Tags: php, mysql, apache

i am getting internal server error while running this query

```
mysql_query("select * from table_name where PARTY LIKE '%NIXON%' group by 1_FROM_2_TO,INSTR_,PARTY limit 1770");
```

but i will get result when change the limit to 1765

```
mysql_query("select * from table_name where PARTY LIKE '%NIXON%' group by 1_FROM_2_TO,INSTR_,PARTY limit 1765");
```

what is the problem here? thanks in advance.

Comment: how about using limit 0, 1770?

Comment: where are you running the query? phpmyadmin?

Comment: How about checking the value of `mysql_error` after the query and finding out what the problem is that way?

Comment: script ran out of memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See your `Error Log`. it may be a mysql problem. check the version of your mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
mysql_query("select * from table_name where PARTY LIKE '%NIXON%' group by 
         1_FROM_2_TO,INSTR_,PARTY limit 0, 1770");
```

**Also,** see your apache `error log`, you will get the Error from `mysql_query`
You can use `die` if `mysql_query()` fails, like

```
$res=mysql_query("select * from table_name where PARTY LIKE '%NIXON%' group by 
         1_FROM_2_TO,INSTR_,PARTY limit 0, 1770") or die(mysql_error());
```

Enabling `error_reporting` can be used to see the `errors` like `notices`, or `warnings`